# Get real size of an 3dObject in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using this code to try to get the actual size of an object in real time, because I'm trying to slice it into two parts. But if I move the object's position, or rotate it, those "size" values ​​change radically, I would like them to only change if and only if the object is smaller or larger, not when I rotate it or change its position

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GetsiZe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 size;
    private MeshRenderer renderer;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
         size = Vector3.Scale(transform.localScale, renderer.bounds.size);
        
        //size = renderer.bounds.size;
        Debug.Log(size);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is a trigger event called a smaller or larger condition, create a method to connect to the trigger event and modify the method to change it.
There is no information on what the conditions for shrinking or increasing in the article are.

Comment: Please add "render = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();" into the Start() method and not inside the Update() method because you only need to cached it once, it's for best practice. Also the current script doesn't show anything that change the scale.

Comment: [Renderer.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) is world space, have you tried [Renderer.localBounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-localBounds.html) instead?

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate. In the first one you will find an explanation to what the `Renderer.bounds` actually is and **why** it changes if you rotate the object, as well a possible solution - note though that this is quite performance heavy to calculate actual mesh based bounds. The second one goes a bit further and is about an oriented bounds since all Unity bounds will anyway always be aligned with the XYZ world axis